# Identifying who deleted products from Magento Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-1, products

I have lost a lot of products from my catalogue seemingly over night (products missing are in sequential order)

I suspect these were deleted from the Magento Admin. (I have the community, not enterprise edition)

How can I see the logs of the computer that I suspect deleted these products?

Comment: This type of functionality does not exist at magento1/magento2. You have to build an extension.

Comment: Thanks - is there nowhere in the logs I can see who has altered what and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in magento 2 by using paid extension of amasty

https://amasty.com/admin-actions-log-for-magento-2.html

try demo of extension: http://demo2.amasty.com/_router/redirect/admin-actions-log-m2/index.php/admin/admin/system_config/edit/section/amaudit/

just delete/edit/add any product you will see action here http://admin-actions-log-m2.demo.amasty.com/admin-actions-log-m2/sessions/309371/index.php/admin/amaudit/actionslog/index/
with username, fullname perform action etc.

find low price extennsion: https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-admin-action-log-extension.html with almost same features

Answer (score 1):

**This is free magento 2 extension.i think this extension will fulfil your need.**

https://github.com/kiwicommerce/magento2-admin-activity

OR

https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/extensions/magento2-admin-activity/

So basically this is third party extension name Admin Activity of KiwiCommerce.this can be used effectively to manage your team’s action when they make any changes on Admin panel. This extension Admin Activity can track all activities of each admin user in the backend and helps to administrate all actions with ease. Furthermore failed attempts of admin login are recorded as well. When a login attempt has failed, you get access to the user’s login information and IP address. When a product, category, customer or any other item is created, updated or deleted in-store or on the website, this extension stores the modified pieces of information with username, date, IP address, user agent, module name and full action path.

Admin Activity extension makes it easy to track every admin activity like admin login, page visit history, add, edit,delete, print, view, mass delete, import, export, mass update etc. It will provide quick answers to common questions, for example:

(a). Who changed the product name?

(b). Who has kept the order on Hold?

(c). Who changed the customer delivery address?